# How to define background for p:menubar in Primefaces?

Tags: css, jsf-2, primefaces, background, menubar

How to define background for `<p:menubar>` in Primefaces

```
<p:menubar rendered="#{loginBO.flag=='admin'}" autoSubmenuDisplay="True" style="background-image: url('images/ui-bg_gloss-wave_55_5c9ccc_500x100_png.png')">
    <p:menuitem value="Home" url="/RMGHome.xhtml" icon="ui-icon-home" />
    <p:menuitem value="Filter Search" action="#{leftMenuService.getMenuList}" icon="ui-icon-search" />
</p:submenu>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
.ui-menubar,.ui-menu-child,.ui-menu {
    background: #004e8e !important;
}
```

Comment: Please explain in own words why you think the `!important` hack is necessary. It namely isn't if you do it right.

Comment: That's not a technical explanation. That's just a picture of a symptom. The `!important` hack is often applied by nitwits if either the selector is not specific enough and/or the CSS file with the selector is incorrectly been loaded *before* the PrimeFaces default CSS. You just need to fix the CSS loading and declaration according proper CSS cascading and inheritance rules instead of falling back to `!important` hack without actually understanding the problem. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-those-classes-defined-in-primefaces-css/8774997#8774997

Comment: Thanks for explaining BalusC and Lamq :)

Answer (score 1):

I used menubar, too and i changed background-color of menubar with css like:

Firstly, i gave a styleClass `<p:menubar styleClass="menubar">`
and then gave it css opsions like below:

```css
<style>
 .menubar {
   background-color: lightblue;
 }
  
</style>
```

```html
<p:menubar styleClass="menubar">
  <p:menuitem value="Main Page" url="index.xhtml" icon="ui-icon-home"></p:menuitem>
</p:menubar>
```

write the above style tag in `<head></head>` tag.
I hope it is useful for you.